# how to expose c++ plugin properties to qml context?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

i have application that load plugins dynamically. each plugin has it's own pluginname.qml file. i need to access the plugins methods from pluginname.qml files.
obviously i can't use QQmlContext::setContextPropert("" ,*object) because of abstract interface of plugins. so what is the proper way to create functionality like this. how can i access the methods of plugin directly from qml(expose plugin methods to qml)? sry for bad english :)

**playerView.qml:**

```
Component.onCompleted:
{
    ViewManager.requestPlugin("playerPlugind.dll"); // ViewManager signal connected to PluginLoader void onPluginRequest() slot
}
```

**PluginLoader.cpp:**

```
bool PluginLoader::loadPlugin(QString plugin_name)
{
  QDir pluginDirectory = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath();
  pluginDirectory.cd("Plugins");
  QPluginLoader pluginLoader(pluginDirectory.filePath(plugin_name));
  QObject* instance = pluginLoader.instance();
  if(instance)
    {
      m_player_interface = qobject_cast<PlayerInterface *>(instance);
      if(m_player_interface )
      return true;
    }
  return 0;
}


void PluginLoader::onPluginRequest(QString plugin_name)
{
  loadPlugin(plugin_name);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this answer is kind of silly ,but we can make a member function in interface class like this :

```
virtual void contextRegister(QQmlContext* rootContext) = 0;
```

then in the plugin we implement the member function:

```
void FirstPlugin::registerContext(QQmlContext* rootContext)
{
    rootContext->setContextProperty("PlayerInterface" , this);
}
```

at the end ,when plugin loaded completely we can call this function :

```
playerInterface->contextRegister(m_rootContext);
```